# highcharts - Custom legend - sending the name of the filter to a php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was able to reverse the behaviour of filters in highcharts so that clicking a series name, filters down, instead of removes the data.

and this is the code I used to do it.

```
                events: {
        legendItemClick: function(event) {
            if (!this.visible)
                return true;

            var seriesIndex = this.index;
            var series = this.chart.series;

            for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
            {
                if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
                {

                    series[i].visible ? series[i].hide() : series[i].show();
                } 
            }

            return false;
        }
    },
```

Now, every time someone clicks on the a filter, I want to send the name of that filter to my php file for further processing, but havn't been able to do so. this is what I've tried

```
                events: {
        legendItemClick: function(event) {
            if (!this.visible)
                return true;

            var seriesIndex = this.index;
            var series = this.chart.series;

            for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
            {
                if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
                {

                    series[i].visible ? series[i].hide() : series[i].show();
                } 
            }

                                                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","/s.php?o="+series,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            return false;
        }


    },
```

I think it could be a problem of not properly calling the name of the filter? where it says series, i've tried

seriesIndex, series, event.point.index.name,   and a lot of others with no luck. my question is if the current code I'm using in that events bracket is correct, and B, if I'm using the right string/variable to call the name of the filter/index.

correction* - using "seriesIndex" as the variable, works to an extent, it will send 0,1,2 (corresponding to the id of the filter), but only when it is the first selection clicked. It ceases to send itself to the php file if it is the 2nd filter clicked.

/// solved thanks to SteveP.

The function calling the php had to go before the first if statement, like this

```
                events: {
        legendItemClick: function(event) {
                                                                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","/s.php?u="+this.name,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            if (!this.visible)
                return true;

            var seriesIndex = this.index;
            var series = this.chart.series;
            for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
            {
                if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
                {
                    series[i].visible ? series[i].hide() : series[i].show();
                } 
            }


            return false;
        }


    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the series name, try:

```
this.name
```

as 'this' should be the selected series, so this.name should be it's name, assuming you gave it one in your chart.

Comment: Ah, yes, "this.name" worked. however, it is only firing to the php during the first click of the filter, if you click another filter, it ceases to fire. Would you happen to have any insight on that as well?

Comment: Does it go into the click callback? Try putting some alerts, or console.log statements to see how far it gets.

Comment: SteveP, I did what you said, added the alerts, and basically spread them all throughout that section to see the flow of code, and I discovered that I had to put my function at the beginning, before the first if statement in the legend section. It works now. I will update the code in my original post. Thank you so much Steve!